# if/or function doesn't work properly

Tags: python, if-statement

i am working on a very simple code, just starting with python actually, but this one problem keeps popping up. i have this code, and many in a similar structure:

```
if input() == "no" or  input() == "i said no" or  input() == "I said no." or  input() == "No.":
        print("Okay! Would you like to teach me more words or quit?")
```

and when i run it, it works but i have to input the answer 4 times for it to register. same with others - i have to input as many times as i have my input in the if function.
i tried adjusting the code like this:

```
if (input() == "no" or  input() == "i said no" or  input() == "I said no."  or  input() == "No."):
        print("Okay! Would you like to teach me more words or quit?")
```

but it still didn't work. how can i solve this issue?

Comment: read the docs help(input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every time you call `input()` means that python will look for input. You want to call `input` only once then save it as a variable and compare that.

```
answer = input('What is your answer?')
if answer  == "no" or  answer  == "i said no" or  answer  == "I said no." or  answer  == "No.":
    print("Okay! Would you like to teach me more words or quit?")
```

better yet, change to something like:

```
if answer in ['no','I said no','I said no.','No']:
```

to get the same effect

Comment: Or use a set literal such as: `if answer in {'no', 'No', 'I said no', 'I said no.'}`

Comment: or: `if answer.lower() in {'no', 'i said no.'}` Probably he forgot to put `.` at the end of `'I said no'`.

Comment: @ozgur indeed - missing the punctuation differences though

Comment: it seems like the best would be `if 'no' in answer.lower()` but I left it up to OP to decide

Comment: thank you! does what i write in the input(brackets) matter? can i leave them like this? input(")

Comment: @veronecka yeah, the parameter is just the message that will be printed as a prompt (so although suggest, not necessary)

Comment: `if 'no' in answer.lower().split()`